# Can we say "you almost got us lost"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, sentence-structure

We can say "**get ready**" and "**get something ready**"

For example, "**I got ready**" and "**I got my file ready**".

When checking the adjective "**lost**" in dictionaries, I only see "**I got lost**" or the like.

My question is that:
Can we say "**get somebody lost**", for example, "**you almost got us lost**"?

Say, you and your friend are going to a place in a city that you are not familiar with like a city in HongKong for example where there are some many complicated small roads.

You both somehow know how to go to that place but not so familiar with it. If you make a mistake and go into a wrong road, then you might get lost.

Now, your friend told you to go that way, but after going 100 meters, you have a gut feeling that that was not the right way & you went back to where you started to avoid getting lost.

In that situation, Is it correct for you to say to your friend "**you almost got us lost**"?

Comment: You realize that "[subject] get lost" means "[subject} become lost" right? Anyway, we'd say:  cause someone to be lost or become lost. "**You almost caused us to get lost or become lost**."

Comment: You can't get somebody else lost, but you can get yourself and companion(s) lost. It seems fine to me as informal language.

Comment: @KateBunting - Couldn't you get somebody else lost by giving them wrong directions?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I suppose so, but it doesn't sound very idiomatic to me.

Comment: @KateBunting - 'My phone got me lost" seems to be fairly common, e.g. _First I attended Mass at Saint Patrick's which was an adventure as both Mapquest and Maps on my phone got me lost._

Comment: @KateBunting What's wrong with caused? Seems the most logical to me.

Comment: @Lambie - I didn't say there was anything wrong with it - my comment was in reply to the question, that 'You almost got us lost' sounded perfectly idiomatic to me.